# How do I run my react components properly?

Tags: reactjs, components

This is my "App.js" code:

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
function App() {
  return (
<div className="Container">
  <Header />
</div>
 )
}
export default App
```

> This is my "Header" code:

```
const Headder = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>task tracker</h1>
            
        </header>
    )
}
export default header
```

My Header and App folder are inside my components folder and my components folder is inside my src folder. i dunno why it doesn't work... Can anyone help me? Fanks

Comment: The problems with the spelling i.e. Header while exporting the component and creating it. And, if your Header and App are inside components, then you can try putting your App outside of components and in the src.

Comment: yaaay it works thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The code in App.js is fine. Just correct your spelling in the Header.js where you have written const **Headder** =(){Your code.}.Change it to const **Header** = () => {Your code} and **export default Header** not **export default header**. Or simply paste this code in your **"Header.js"**

Header.js file:

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>task tracker</h1>
        </header>
            )
        }
 export default Header
```

Be consistent with your spellings. It gives a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
export default header
```

to

```
export default Header
```

Comment: Also const Headder =()=>{} to const Header=()=>{}